# How to implement implicit numerical methods in python?

Tags: python, numpy, numerical-methods, ode

I have a set of stiff differential equations and I first tried to integrate them using the 4th-order Runge-Kutta implemented as follows:

```
def rk4_step(r, u, h, f, *args):
    k1 = h * f(r, u, *args)
    k2 = h * f(r + h/2, u + k1/2, *args)
    k3 = h * f(r + h/2, u + k2/2, *args)
    k4 = h * f(r + h, u + k3, *args)
    u_new = u + (k1 + 2.0 * k2 + 2.0 * k3 + k4)/6.0
    return u_new
```

However, I realized that the results were wrong (a very small change in the `h` step would change the equation too much)

[image: Plot]

Precisely because the Runge-Kutta method is not used to resolve stiff ODEs. I researched and saw that the backward differentiation formula method or the Radau method would be a good option for this case. I tried to implement manually like this:

```
def bdf2_step(r, u, h, f, *args):
    a = [[(88-7*sqrt(6))/360, (296-169*sqrt(6))/1800, (-2+3*sqrt(6))/225], [(296+169 *sqrt(6))/1800, (88+7*sqrt(6))/360, (-2-3*sqrt(6))/225], [(16-sqrt(6))/36, ( 16+sqrt(6))/36, 1/9]]
    b = [(16-sqrt(6))/36, (16+sqrt(6))/36, 1/9]
    c = [(4-sqrt(6))/10, (2+sqrt(6))/10, 1]
    k1 = h * f(r + c[0] * h, u + (a[0][0]*k1 + a[0][1]*k2 + a[1][2]*k3))
    k2 = h * f(r + c[1] * h, u + (a[1][0]*k1 + a[1][1]*k2 + a[1][2]*k3))
    k3 = h * f(r + c[2] * h, u + (a[2][0]*k1 + a[2][1]*k2 + a[2][2]*k3))
    u_new = u + (b[1]*k1 + b[2]*k2 + b[3]*k3)
    return u_new
```

But, because it is an implicit method, the code presents an error for not having defined `k1`, `k2` and `k3` previously.

How I can implement this method manually in a way that doesn't give this error?

I've tried to solve it before with `scipy.integrate` and `solve_ivp`, but it still gives the same problem with the small change of step `h` in the results. I would like to implement the numbers method manually to have more control over errors and data.

Comment: You could try using a predictor–corrector method, root finding, or use some other method to first find k1, k2, k3 and then use `bdf2_step` after.

Comment: Going by experience with several people trying similar things: It will very likely be a lot of work for you to create an integrator that is somehow better than a pre-implemented one, even for your specific application. Most likely, your time is better spent trying to find out why your solution using an existing integrator fails. In your particular case, it is striking that there are considerable differences in certain variables at the very beginning, which suggests that the initial conditions do not match for some reason.

Comment: Your structure in bdf2 is not that of a backward differentiation formula, which is a linear multi-step method, but of an implicit one-step aka Runge-Kutta method, possibly a Radau method. Please clean this up. Implicit methods always require an iterative equation solver to guarantee the order and accuracy of the method. For experimental purposes use `fsolve` from scipy.optimize, but this is a slow variant.